# bootnodes on Parity

Tags: parity, bootnodes

Do you have to do anything special to create a bootnode on Parity?  I was just using the Parity enodes in a private genesis file.

I guess I have to open port 30301?

Anything else?

Answer (score 2):

To run a bootnode, you should

1. increase your `--max-peers` to something sensible like `1024`,
2. make sure port `30303` is open (or whatever your node's network port is)

Other than that, that's it. Bootnodes are just normal nodes. It's recommended to have decent hardware though, especially for larger networks.

Comment: So 30304/UDP is not necessary?  I assumed 30303 and 30304/UDP were necessary but you specified 30303 so the question of 30304/UDP comes up.  Also please explain the --max-peers reason?